# Evaluating Statements Using a Parse Tree

Tags: algorithms, graph-traversal, interpreters, syntax-trees

I'm building a compiler. I already have a parse tree which I built using Bison for a grammar similar to the ANSI C grammar in this [link](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html#postfix-expression). I see that for multiplicative expression in my parse tree, there can be 3 children e.g.

```
child 1: multiplicative_expression 
child 2: '*'
child 3: cast_expression
```

I expect to implement a new class for interpreting the parse tree. However, I have no idea how to even traverse the parse tree in order to evaluate the statements. How do I traverse the tree properly in order to interpret all the types of statements? I want to interpret not only multiplicative statements but also if-else statements etc.

Comment: Which tree traversals do you know? Are you familiar with recursion? What do you mean by "interprete"; translate? (A note of concern: compilers are complex, intricate beasts. Are you sure you are ready to build on yourself, given you have such elementary (read: first or second year in a CS course) issues?)

Comment: @Raphael I'm familiar with traversal for binary trees, but my "parse tree" is not a binary tree. Yes, I'm familiar with recursion and I have tried recursing expression statements until I see a postfix expression but I'm concerned about which values to save during parsing. I'm ready to build one myself but I'm in need of finding the logic for statements. It seems like there's a way to recognize statements (including expression statements) and I have yet to find it. Please help, Sir.

Comment: With interpret, I meant that I want to have a runtime environment that executes the code.

Comment: Hint: post-order. The rest, I'm afraid, is programming (as far as I cantell) and hence offtopic here. (A C interpreter? Not that it's really relevant, but why?)

Comment: @Raphael something like a C interpreter (or a compiler) for educational purpose. Could you give me some description of the algorithm to interpret the statements? I have read the Shuntingyard algorithm for mathematical expressions. Maybe the algorithms for the current problem have names or something?

Comment: @b16db0 3 remarks: a compiler is different from an interpreter. When given an
expression, a compiler translates it into another language, while an
interpreter computes its value from the values of the variables it is
using. Which are you doing? Then you should fist start with a very
simple language ... far far less complicated than the link you give.
I would suggest a language without types (use only integer), and only
expressions, assignment and if statement ... just for training. And
you should read books on this topic (interpreters and compilers).

Comment: Agree with @babou. For writing an interpreter, you'll also have to dig deep into the semantics (not only the syntax) of C.

Comment: @babou I'm actually writing a compiler for the intermediate code, and an interpreter which will interpret the intermediate code.

Comment: In this case, much depends on the nature of the intermediate code. Most likely expressions no longer appear as such in intermediate code, so that my answer is moot. What the compiler does, most likely, is translate an expression into a succession of intermediate commands that do what is needed to compute the evaluation of the expression. But the execution of this intermediate code for actual evaluation can occur only at run-time, when all variables used have a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An expression is composed usually of an operator (or function) applied
to some arguments, or in the simplest case, just a constant (aka
literal) or a variable.

For evaluation:
The value of a constant is that constant, The value for
a variable is the current value stored in that variable, as each
variable corresponds to a memory location where values can be stored.
The value of an operator or function applied to arguments is obtained
by evaluating arguments (recursively) and then applying the operator or
function to the values thus obtained.

Actually, things can be more complex for a function (and some
operator), depending on parameter passing mechanisms or evaluation
modes (lazy or not), but that is to complex to explain at this level
of discourse.

In your example the operator is child 2, and the two other children
are arguments.

In general the algorithm does pretty much what you would do if you had
to interpret the program by hand. That should be a good guide.