# Evaluating Functions Using a Parse Tree

Tags: programming-languages, interpreters, syntax-trees

I'm making a compiler/interpreter for a language similar to C. I already have a parse tree. I was able to evaluate expression statements by converting my code to another language and then using an evaluation engine. How do I properly evaluate functions using a parse tree? Let's say my function x looks like the following:

```
x(int a, int b){
    x = <some expression statement using a and b>
    <some function call using x>
}
```

How can i be able to save the statements so that whenever the function is called, the contained statements will be evaluated?

Comment: Hm, what's wrong with the obvious answer: store the parse tree? You [already know](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/33256/98) how to evaluate the body once the parameters are set. Meta hint: read a book on compilers, e.g. the Dragon book. (You are busy reinventing the wheel.)

Comment: @Raphael I really appreciate your replies. I finally found out that I have to store a part of the parse tree and then retrieve that piece whenever a function call is made. I'm now solving the issue of how I can properly assign values to the parameters of the function.

Comment: How do you model state? Passing `a` and `b` has the same effect as having only the body but preceded by `a = ...` and `b = ...` -- follow the formal semantics there.

Comment: If your language is similar to C, it allows recursion. That implies that you must be using a stack of activation records. That implies using specific technique to find what memory location is associated with a variable during execution of a function. Keeping the parse-tree for evaluation of the body is not quite what I would call compilation. I would rather convert it to the other language, and keep that as the code to be evaluated when calling the function. Essentially a compiled function is the description of an activation record to be created at call time, and some code to be executed.

Comment: @Raphael I didn't understand what you meant when you said "model state". But I think I get your point that the parameters will be processed first before the function body.

Comment: @babou I have to review activation records. Do you have a blog or something? I think I can learn a lot from you Sir, considering that most of your tags are about programming languages.

Comment: @b16db0 That's what I meant, I think. Be aware of call-by-value, call-by-reference, call-by-name and whatever else there is, though!

Comment: @b16db0 Regarding your request, my e-mail is in my profile. But it is
better to ask questions here, or even better to try to answer by
yourself by searching on the web, wikipedia and other sources. When
you ask here, it is better to explain what you have tried and where
you looked, and be precise as to what you do not understand.
Activation records is a well documented topic.